# I need to test a condition within the sql in postgis.

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I need to test a condition within the sql in postgis. 
My sql:

```
SELECT
    (zoneamento3_32722.zt3),
    logradouros32722."NMIDEABR",
    logradouros32722."OBJECTID",
    "public".logradouros32722."NRIMPINI",
    "public".logradouros32722."NRIMPFIN",
    "public".logradouros32722."NRPARINI",
    "public".logradouros32722."NRPARFIN"
FROM
    "public".logradouros32722,
    "public".zoneamento3_32722
WHERE
    st_within (
        logradouros32722.geom,
        zoneamento3_32722.geom
    )
AND logradouros32722."NMIDELOG" LIKE 'IPIRANGA%'

/ / if odd goes here
AND (
    logradouros32722."NRIMPINI" <= 60
    AND logradouros32722."NRIMPFIN" >= 60

/ / if pair goes here

AND
 (
        logradouros32722."NRPARINI" <= 60
        AND logradouros32722."NRPARFIN" >= 60
    )
)
```

Comment: What is the question? You posted the code but it's hard to guess what's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Postgresql CASE statement to assign some value (category) based upon a condition, but I'd put it in the SELECT clause (not the WHERE clause):

```
SELECT z.zt3, l."NMIDEABR", l."OBJECTID", l."NRIMPINI", l."NRIMPFIN", l."NRPARINI",l."NRPARFIN",
  (CASE
    WHEN l."NRIMPINI" <= 60 AND l."NRIMPFIN" >= 60 THEN "odd";
    ELSE "pair";
  END CASE) as category 
FROM "public".logradouros32722 l, "public".zoneamento3_32722 z
WHERE st_within (l.geom, z.geom)
AND l."NMIDELOG" LIKE 'IPIRANGA%';
```